# JSON call inside object failing. Uncaught Reference: data is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop

When I instantiate an object, it should fetch data using jQuery's getJSON method and fill the object's properties from that data. Instead, I get `Uncaught Reference: data is not defined` on the AJAX call. `data`, in this case, is the name of the JSON data object argument I'm passing to my callback function.

My constructor:

```
function HeadlineList(url) {
    this.url = url;

    this.checkEmpty = function() {
        if (this.headlines === 0) {
            this.refreshContent();
        }
    };

    this.getRandom = function(remove) {
        var headlineNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*this.quantity);
        var headline = this.headlines[headlineNumber];
        if (remove) {
            this.deleteHeadline(headlineNumber);
        }
        return headline;
    };

    this.getHeadline = function(number, remove) {
        var headline = this.headlines[number]
        if (remove) {
            this.deleteHeadline(number);
        }
        return headline;
    };

    this.deleteHeadline = function(number) {
        this.headlines.splice(number, 1);
        this. quantity -= 1;
    };

    this.fillFromJSON = function(data) {
      this.headlines = data.headlines;
      this.quantity = this.list.length;
    };

    this.refreshContent = function() {
        $.getJSON(this.url, this.fillFromJSON(data));
    };

    this.refreshContent();
}
```

I'm instantiating an object like so:

```
headlines = new HeadlineList('js/headlines.json');
```

Can anyone help me figure out why this doesn't work?

Comment: Get rid of `(data)`, you want to pass a reference to the function, not the value returned from the function.

Comment: ^^^^ +1, should be `$.getJSON(this.url, this.fillFromJSON);`

Comment: @KevinB means that you should change the `$.getJSON()` call. The way you've got it, you're **calling** the "fillFromJSON" function rather than setting it up as the callback.

Comment: This all makes great sense. Thanks, everyone. Now, I'm on to the next problem. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When passing a function reference as a callback to $.getJSON, you want to pass a reference to the function. You do not need to name the parameters at this point.

```
$.getJSON(url,myFunction);
```

The parameters are already named here:

```
myFunction = function(data) {
   ...
}
```

If you instead do

```
$.getJSON(url,myFunction(data));
```

you are actually executing myFunction immediately, and then passing the value returned from it (`undefined`) as the callback to `$.getJSON()`